# Image popup and follows mouse when hover on text --> problem when scroll down

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, tooltip

Im working on a image (in this case, a red square) that pops up and follows the mouse when you hover on a specific text.

The problem is that, although it works perfect at the beginning, once I scroll down the image changes the distance with the mouse, getting eventually lost. It seems I am doing something wrong but I cannot really see it.

Here I attach the code:

```js
  $('.imagetooltip').mousemove(function (e) {
  $('span', this).css({left: e.pageX + 0, top: e.pageY + 0});
});
```

```css
.imagetooltip span {
  position: fixed;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity .5s ease-in-out;
}

.imagetooltip:hover span {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<ul id="listcontainer">
      <li class="imagetooltip">
        <p>HERE A SHORT TEXT</p><span><div class="home-img" style="height: 300px; width: 600px; background: red"></span>
      </li>
      <li class="imagetooltip">
        <p>HERE A SHORT TEXT</p><span><div class="home-img" style="height: 300px; width: 600px; background: red"></span>
      </li>
      <li class="imagetooltip">
        <p>HERE A SHORT TEXT</p><span><div class="home-img" style="height: 300px; width: 600px; background: red"></span>
      </li>
      <li class="imagetooltip">
        <p>HERE A SHORT TEXT</p><span><div class="home-img" style="height: 300px; width: 600px; background: red"></span>
      </li>
      <li class="imagetooltip">
        <p>HERE A SHORT TEXT</p><span><div class="home-img" style="height: 300px; width: 600px; background: red"></span>
      </li>
      <li class="imagetooltip">
        <p>HERE A SHORT TEXT</p><span><div class="home-img" style="height: 300px; width: 600px; background: red"></span>
      </li>
      <li class="imagetooltip">
        <p>HERE A SHORT TEXT</p><span><div class="home-img" style="height: 300px; width: 600px; background: red"></span>
      </li>
      <li class="imagetooltip">
        <p>HERE A SHORT TEXT</p><span><div class="home-img" style="height: 300px; width: 600px; background: red"></span>
      </li>
      <li class="imagetooltip">
        <p>HERE A SHORT TEXT</p><span><div class="home-img" style="height: 300px; width: 600px; background: red"></span>
      </li>
      <li class="imagetooltip">
        <p>HERE A SHORT TEXT</p><span><div class="home-img" style="height: 300px; width: 600px; background: red"></span>
      </li>
      <li class="imagetooltip">
        <p>HERE A SHORT TEXT</p><span><div class="home-img" style="height: 300px; width: 600px; background: red"></span>
      </li>
      <li class="imagetooltip">
        <p>HERE A SHORT TEXT</p><span><div class="home-img" style="height: 300px; width: 600px; background: red"></span>
      </li>
      <li class="imagetooltip">
        <p>HERE A SHORT TEXT</p><span><div class="home-img" style="height: 300px; width: 600px; background: red"></span>
      </li>
      <li class="imagetooltip">
        <p>HERE A SHORT TEXT</p><span><div class="home-img" style="height: 300px; width: 600px; background: red"></span>
      </li>
      <li class="imagetooltip">
        <p>HERE A SHORT TEXT</p><span><div class="home-img" style="height: 300px; width: 600px; background: red"></span>
      </li>
      <li class="imagetooltip">
        <p>HERE A SHORT TEXT</p><span><div class="home-img" style="height: 300px; width: 600px; background: red"></span>
      </li>
      <li class="imagetooltip">
        <p>HERE A SHORT TEXT</p><span><div class="home-img" style="height: 300px; width: 600px; background: red"></span>
      </li>
      <li class="imagetooltip">
        <p>HERE A SHORT TEXT</p><span><div class="home-img" style="height: 300px; width: 600px; background: red"></span>
      </li>
      <li class="imagetooltip">
        <p>HERE A SHORT TEXT</p><span><div class="home-img" style="height: 300px; width: 600px; background: red"></span>
      </li>
      <li class="imagetooltip">
        <p>HERE A SHORT TEXT</p><span><div class="home-img" style="height: 300px; width: 600px; background: red"></span>
      </li>
    </ul>
```

I will appreciate any suggestion/improvement in the code :)

Thanks a lot in advance and cheers!

*Note: The code snippet is not able to move the red square and follow the mouse, but when I run the code locally I don't get any JQuery problem :S

Answer (score 0):

**First thing,** `span` is an inline element and `div` is block element. So having a `div` inside `span` isn't a good practice, also, it would be better, if you nest `span` inside `span` and give inner `span` `display:block` or `display: inline-block` property.

**secondly,** change `position: fixed` to `position:absolute.`

```
.imagetooltip span {
      position: absolute;
      opacity: 0;
      transition: opacity .5s ease-in-out;
 }
```